# I need combobox style with rounded borders

Tags: wpf, combobox, rounded-corners

I want to ask how to make rounded corners for wpf combobox and how to set custom background for the items and how to change the drop down icon shap something like photo
[image]

I tried to put border but it doesn't work correctly

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the CornerRadius of the Combobox WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727879/how-to-change-the-cornerradius-of-the-combobox-wpf)

Comment: Thanks alot, I have tried this style to my combobox but it didn't make the shape I want of combo

Comment: Your images look identical. What shape you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve the shape in the photos, i cant make a style for it in my code